# How to use videojs player with Angular and video source from a server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video.js

I'm using video js player on my web site. (http://videojs.com/getting-started/) i'm using AngularJS. Here's my issue.

First I tried to use normal video js codes as shown in the example.

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="607" height="343"
           poster="http://demo.jpg"
           data-setup='{"loop":false,"autoplay":false}'>
        <source ng-src="{{ moblileURL }}"
                type='video/mp4'>
        <p class="vjs-no-js">
            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
        </p>
    </video>
```

I have used src as {{ mobileURL }} because it's loading from the server. And here's my Angular controller code.

```
videoService.viewVideoByVidId(videoId, "VideoMobile").then(function (data) {
        $scope.moblileURL = data.flvurl;
        console.log("FLV URL For Mobile : ", $scope.moblileURL);
    });
```

This is the place I assign url to the varibale. When I use the code like this, I'm getting the following error.

> Can't interpolate: {{ moblileURL }}
>   Error: [$sce:insecurl] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$sce/insecurl?p0=http%...

And then I use the function like this and see the code here.

> $scope.moblileURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data.flvurl);

Then also I'm getting an error.. This is the error.

> video.js:19296VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

Then I tried to use a custom directive. This is a github repo to that code.
https://github.com/LonnyGomes/vjs-video. In this code, I get the same error. Please can someone tell me how to fix this ? This is the second directive I have tried so far.

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto"
           width="607" height="343" poster="http://demo.jpg"
           vjs-video>
        <source src="{{ moblileURL }}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

How can I render this correctly ? Can anyone suggest me a better way ?

Comment: Not an answer, but a hypothesis: the video tag is being picked up before the scripts are ready. As a result, there is no video to play before Angular inserts the script src.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Cannot explain why, but I created a custom directive that wraps the `<video>` tag; in the link function I manually insert the source tag:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     angular.element(element).find('video').append("<source src='" + scope.src + "' type='" + scope.type + "' />")
}
```

and this is working... Probably at loading the videojs library finds a source tag with no src yet interpolated, so it crashes...

Answer (score 0):

When using `vjs-video`, you can use data binding to define the source locations. When the data is updated, the vjs-video directive will bootstrap video.js for you. You could define the data as follows:

```
$source.media = {
    sources: [
        {
            src: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',
            type: 'video/mp4'
        },
        {
            src: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm',
            type: 'video/webm'
        }
    ],
    tracks: [
        {
            kind: 'subtitles',
            label: 'English subtitles',
            src: 'assets/subtitles.vtt',
            srclang: 'en',
            default: true
        }
    ],
    poster: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png'
};
```

This object can then can be referenced in the directive:

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls 
       preload="auto" vjs-video vjs-media="media">
</video>
```

The documentation for `vis-media` can be found [here](https://github.com/LonnyGomes/vjs-video#vjs-media). For a full example, take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/LonnyGomes/d75e8c1704668283e049).